# Notation when describing properties of a periodic function

Tags: periodic-functions

When describing intervals of increase, intervals of decrease, and the domain, does it have to be for the same period? For example for the graph of $$y=\sec(x)$$
[image]

Is it correct to describe the intervals as such:

- Domain: $\bigl[x \in \bigl(-\frac{3\pi}{2}, -\frac{\pi}{2}\bigr) \cup \bigl(-\frac{\pi}{2} , \frac{\pi}{2}\bigr)\bigr] + 2\pi k, \quad k \in \mathbb{Z} $
- Interval of increase:  $\bigl[\bigl(0, \frac{\pi}{2}\bigr) \cup \bigl( \frac{\pi}{2} , \pi\bigr)\bigr] + 2\pi k,\quad k \in \mathbb{Z}$
- Interval of decrease: $\bigl[\bigl(-\pi, -\frac{\pi}{2}\bigr) \cup \bigl(-\frac{\pi}{2} , 0\bigr)\bigr] + 2\pi k,\quad k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: As a help, you can compare with the solution that gives WA: [increasing f(x)=sec(x)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=increasing+f%28x%29%3Dsec%28x%29).

Comment: Almost correct. For the intervals of , $0$ and $\pi$ belong to the intervals.

Comment: @Bernard What do you mean? I don't think I understand what you're saying.

Comment: The intervals should be $\bigl[0, \frac{\pi}{2}\bigr) \cup \bigl( \frac{\pi}{2} , \pi\bigr]$ and $\bigl[-\pi, -\frac{\pi}{2}\bigr) \cup \bigl(-\frac{\pi}{2} , 0\bigr]$ respectively.